# how to create RestFull Api for already existing yii2 app

Tags: php, json, rest, yii

I have created an `Yii2` app.
Now i want to create `RestFull Api` for this app.
I have read about this topic at `yii` doc.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html

I can create code for fresh app but i want to create for already existing app.
I have an `e-commerce` app and i want my all function also work with `Rest'.

Please help or let me know if my question is not clear.

Thank you

Comment: If you use modules then create a new module for api. I think this link will helpful for you http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/

Comment: Thak you for reply. I checked the above link but my question is how can I make already existing function as `RestApi`. I mean i have function for `AddToCart`, `Checkout` etc. now if i go the way as in above link then i need to create every function again.